# Automatically publish packages to NPM with CircleCI

Tags: npm, circleci

I'm trying to set up automated deployments for a public NPM package in CircleCI. What I'd like is for CircleCI to automatically publish the package to NPM whenever the version number has changed in `package.json` has changed. Is that possible with CircleCI?

Comment: Is the build changing the version number or is it being changed somewhere and then committed?

Comment: The version number would be changed in the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Obtain the npm authToken for the account that you wish to use to publish the package.
 You can do that by logging in to npm (npm login). This will save the authToken to the ~/.npmrc file.

2- Go to your project settings in circleci.com, and set the NPM_TOKEN variable to the obtained authToken.

3- In your cicle.yml add a this section

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" >> ~/.npmrc

deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - npm publish
```

Whenever you commit to master branch, it will trigger npm publish.

[More information in the official documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/npm-continuous-deployment/)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!